# mod_rewrite conflict with other $_GET vars

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am using mod_rewrite to make my URLs clean. By doing so:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?page=$1&sub=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?page=$1&sub=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1&sub=$2&id=$3
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?page=$1&sub=$2&id=$3
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?page=$1&sub=$2&action=$3
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?page=$1&sub=$2&action=$3
```

This changes everything nicely from for example:
`website.com/index.php?page=user&sub=profile` to `website.com/user/profile/`.

But what if there are other `$_GET` variables AFTER profile. So for example, if the user calls for:
`website.com/user/profile/?do=that&go=ahead`

When I try to print `$_GET['do']` and `$_GET['go']`, they return empty.

Any ideas?

Suggestions to make my mod_rewrite code shorter are also welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case, you need to add the [QSA flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa). Furthermore, I'd say that all your 6 rules are basically doing the same. You can add optional sections to your regular expressions with the `?` operator. For instance, these lines:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?page=$1&sub=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?page=$1&sub=$2
```

... can be merged as:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&sub=$2 [QSA]
```